# How to rewrite a method into a hash

Tags: java, csv

I have an assignment and im supposed to rewrite a method that should be made into a hash. This is the code given. When i type in getOrderByState("shipped") at my main, it should print out all orders that have 'shipped' as their status. I have attached the csv [here][1]

````
 //    public ArrayList<Order> getOrdersByState(String inState ){
   //            //ToDo: Rewrite this method to be more efficent and use a hash
   //        ArrayList<Order> retOrder = new ArrayList<>();
   //        //boolean firstLine = true;
   //        for( Order o : orders ){
   //            if ( o.getStatus().equals(inState) ){
   //                retOrder.add(o);
   //            }
   //        }
   //        return retOrder;
   //    }

So far i have come up with this

   public ArrayList<Order> getOrdersByState(String inState ) {
       //ToDo: Rewrite this method to be more efficent and use a hash
       ArrayList<Order> retOrder = new ArrayList<>();
       HashMap<String, List<Order>> map = new HashMap<>();
       boolean firstLine = true;
       for (Order o : orders) {
           if (firstLine) {
               firstLine = false;
               continue;
           }
               if (map.containsKey(inState)) {
                   map.put(inState,o);
               }
           }
           return retOrder;

   }
}

``` but the o in (instate, o) is red 

 [1]: https://notepad.link/r3xys
````

Comment: Please edit your question to include a runnable example which illustrates your problem.

Comment: What do you think `if (byOrderStatus.contains(inState)) {` does? When is it true? When is it false?

Comment: You should use HashMap<String, List<Order>> to store orders grouped by status

Comment: how would i know when to use a hashset vs a hashmap?

Comment: HashSet is like an ArrayList, but does not allow duplicates. HashMap is a pair KEY - VALUE

Comment: fyi, "a hash" is a mathematical function, not the hash set / hash map / hash table data structures even though they use such a hash function to achieve O(1) access.

Comment: *how would i know when to use a hashset vs a hashmap?*  Sets and Maps are fundamentally different. A set is a collection of (unique) things.  A map allows you to look up a thing by another sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is 3 alternatives to convert your List into Map.

I didn't write the complete code with your function names, to allow you learn how this works, and practice.

```
List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
// your code to fill orders list....
// orders.add(new Order(......));

Map<String, List<Order>> ordersByStatusMap;

// convert List to Map (previous than Java 8)
ordersByStatusMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Order order : orders) {
    List<Order> orderList = ordersByStatusMap.get(order.getStatus());
    if (orderList == null) {
        orderList = new ArrayList<>();
        ordersByStatusMap.put(order.getStatus(), orderList);
    }
    orderList.add(order);
}

// convert List to Map using loop and lambda functions on Map (Java 8 or high)
ordersByStatusMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Order order : orders) {
    ordersByStatusMap.computeIfAbsent(order.getStatus(), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(order);
}

// convert List to Map using lambda stream (Java 8 or high)
ordersByStatusMap = orders.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Order::getStatus));
```

After this, since you have stored the orders grouped by what you need (the STATUS), your function just need to get the orders by status on the map

```
return ordersByStatusMap.get(inState);
```

WARNING: If is required to never return null, you should check for null previous than return, and if null, return an empty list (ex: `Collections.emptyList();` ).